# TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollToIndex' for google pixele 2 phone

Tags: react-native, expo

`google notifies me of this error when I submit my application Cannot read property 'scrollToIndex' for google pixele 2 phone I don't know where the error comes from

```
Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollToIndex' of null, js engine: hermes, stack:
anonymous@1:2941090
anonymous@1:230509
\_callTimer@1:229657
callTimers@1:231395
\__callFunction@1:81578
anonymous@1:80073
\__guard@1:81012
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@1:80031
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:65)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run`
```